# Which iPad Mini is model FD528LL/A?

Tags: ipad

I'm trying to identify a friend's iPad Mini.  I know the model number from the "About" screen is FD528LL/A.  Unfortunately, I don't have the model number from the back of the iPad.  Is this an iPad Mini 1, 2, 3, or 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend has a Refurbished [iPad Mini (1st Generation, 16GB, Wi-Fi Only, Black)](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-mini-original-a1432-wi-fi-only-specs.html).

The number on the back should say [A1432](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models#iPad_mini).

The F generally indicates a refurbished product (not always).